# Having notepad++ running at startup minimized

Tags: notepad++, startup, minimized

as title says, i'm on Windows 10 x64 and the installation path is "c:\program files" so i've to create a new string in regedit after ..\syswow64\current version\run with c:\program files\notepad++\notepad++.exe.
So far so good. Now i want it to start and open minimized but i didnt find any infos on the net regarding it. I've found -systray (as shown [here](https://www.mojeprogramy.com/notepad/linia-komend.php) command line but as i said i want it minimized like when you do with a .lnk and not minimized.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks
Frost

Comment: Why are you touching the registry? For this simple case you should use the startup folder and put a link in there with the launch properties set to minimized (see for example https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-automatically-start-a-program-minimized-in-windows/ )

Comment: Because as i said i'm on Windows 10 x64 and the only way to put on startup x64 programs is by adding in the registry the program path after syswow64 entry

Comment: Have you tried running the command `shell:startup` (with the Win+R shortcut I mean) ?

Comment: Yes, and there are x86 programs which i've already created a shortcut in...but for notepad++ x64bit i still need help on how to put it minimized on startup as it still in the regedit (\Syswow64\...\Run)